# Three column sticky layout with independent scrolling with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, sticky

I've seen similar questions asked here, but none of the solutions have worked for me. I have a three column layout (flexbox) and **need to have the following behavior**:

1. Each of the three columns scrolls (vertically) independent of the other columns
2. Each column becomes sticky (fixed in place) when it reaches the bottom of the main nav

**[Here's my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emontherun/oyfz4xsb/13/)**

**Preferences:**

1. Prefer pure CSS option, if possible
2. Prefer to not move HTML elements around, as we have a very dynamic website where content, errors, etc. are added to different places based on many different factors

**Note:** As you can see, i've got the left sidebar / nav working like I want, now just trying to get the others in same state.

**Here's what worked on the left-nav:**

```css
.left-nav-menu {
  position: sticky;
  align-self: flex-start;
  top: 0;
  height: calc(100vh - 4em);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

[Here's my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emontherun/oyfz4xsb/13/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried these and what I did was to duplicate elements so as not to affect the aggregation of dynamic content with JavaScript.
-Duplicate the header element and add the class "sub-header-sticky"
-Duplicate the div element and add it with the class "p-x-xl" and add the class "entity-types-contents" to it.
-Also add a "sub-header-width" class, to control the width of the last 2 header sections.
I hope it helps you or guides you to a better solution!
[Here's my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marvin90/j4yh8nvd/2/)

```css
.sub-header-width {
  width: 62%;
}
.sub-header-sticky {
  position: sticky;
  align-self: flex-start;
  top: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.entity-types-contents {
  position: sticky;
  align-self: flex-start;
  top: 0;
  height: calc(100vh - 17em);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```